# Remove Old SKPayment From Queue

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, storekit

In-app purchases are working correctly with my app. I'm even using my own server to validate transaction receipts.

However, I seem to be having an issue with the SKPaymentQueue **TransactionObserver** and/or **DefaultQueue**.

An iTunes prompt, *for an old test account*, will appear whenever I make the following call -

```
SKPaymentQueue *currentQueue = [SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue];
```

I cannot figure out how to stop this old test account from appearing whenever I need to make a purchase or restore transactions.

Someone has recommended the following code, which would appear to finish all old transactions, but it doesn't resolve my issue.

```
SKPaymentQueue* currentQueue = [SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue];
[currentQueue.transactions enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
[currentQueue finishTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)obj];
```

}];

I've also tried removing the app, deleting the old test account from the device and also iTunesConnect. The old user prompt still appears!

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

are they sandbox transactions or production transactions?

sandbox transactions are a big mess, sometime i find old transactions in the queue, and the lifecycle of sandbox transactions is not totally coherent with production transactions's lifecycle

Comment: Yeah, I'm using the sandbox API for the time-being. Hmmm interesting you say that, that could explain things. Although I'm not sure if I'd be confident releasing the app hoping that it was in fact just the sandbox transactions acting up.

Comment: I had same doubts, and I spent days trying to understand what was appening to my sandbox queue

Then I decided to ignore them and release the app, and I discovered that this are only sandbox problems...

Comment: Glad I'm not the only one who's come across this. Will I still keep getting these dodgy transactions on my test device even after it's in production / downloaded from the store? I presume the queue is tied to my device in some way...

Answer (score 0):

I just solved the same problem in my code. The issue was because I was not removing the transaction observer when the app would quit.

add this to your app delegate:

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{   
   [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] removeTransactionObserver:self.storeManager]; 
}


- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
{   
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] removeTransactionObserver:self.storeManager];
}
```

I also needed to restart my devices to make sure they were completely clear. Then when you do a restore all purchases the system should be back to normal.